# JPA and Mysql query on play framework

Tags: jpa, playframework

I am new and i need help about using JPA on play framework.

Anyone can give me a sample about convert mysql query to JPA? or good Tutorials？

Better with example or sample code. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Play!Framework has very good documentation on this topic, go and check http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/jpa#finding.

You can also find many useful code from the samples packaged in the installation package